# Removing nested list in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

This is my input data.

```
data = {323: [[639, 646]], 325: [[1491, 1507]], 332: [[639, 647], [823, 833], [1274, 1298]], 334: [[640, 646]], 335: [[822, 834]]}
```

I want to remove the sublist whose values are lesser than or equal to 10.

My output would look like this.

```
output_data = {323: [], 325:[[1491,1507]], 332:[[1274,1298]], 334:[], 335:[[822,834]]}
```

How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: Can you clarify on the requirement above? "whose values are lesser than or equal to 10" - I noticed that this is never the case though.

Comment: By values i mean the elements inside the sublist of list (639,646), (1491,1507)... and so on.

Comment: I think the condition is that the values *differ* by less than or equal to 10.

Comment: Yes, i mean those too. But for example, I don't understand how 639 is less than or equal to 10.

Comment: I want to compute the difference of these elements. If the difference is <= 10, then I want to eliminate those sublists and the output would look like the one I posted above.

Comment: @Blckknght you are much more perceptive than me, thanks

Comment: To make it clear for you, The difference between (646 - 639) is <= 10. So, I want to remove the sublist [639,646].

Comment: How can I achieve my output. Can you share your ideas on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did a quick test, and looks like it's possible to do this using a `dict` comprehension and the `filter` buitin function:

```py
result = {k: list(filter(lambda v: v[1] - v[0] > 10, val_list))
          for k, val_list in data.items()}

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{323: [], 325: [[1491, 1507]], 332: [[1274, 1298]], 334: [], 335: [[822, 834]]}
```

**Assumption:** The sublists are sorted with lowest element first, and then higher element next. If not, you'll need to wrap it with an `abs` call, like `abs(v[1] - v[0])` to be safe, in case `v[0]` is the higher element.

Comment: Hold on.. this solution is actually not right in some cases.

Comment: For example if you move `[1274, 1298]` in 332 to the first place instead, then it will result in an empty sublist.

Comment: @TaarunSrinivas I've updated the answer, it should now give the correct result in these cases as well

Answer (score 1):

You can write a list comprehension that re-builds the list of lists for each key in the dictionary, with a conditional that the difference of the items in the inner is greater than 10:

```
for key, values in data.items():
    data[key] = [[low, high] for low, high in values if high - low > 10]
```